# what's the time complexity of finding all nullable symbols in context free grammar?

Tags: context-free

I'm reading Hopcroft's book about computation theory and wondering about how fast can u find all nullable symbols in CFG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in linear time.  For each nonterminal $A$, introduce a boolean variable $x_A$ that identifies whether $A$ is nullable or not.  Derive constraints on these boolean variables, following [the relations described by Hopcroft and Ullman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#DEL:_Eliminate_%CE%B5-rules).  Note that all of these constraints are Horn clauses.  Now find the least solution to this system of Horn clauses.  This can be done in linear time (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability).

---

If you want a self-contained algorithm that runs in linear time, build a bipartite graph, with one left-vertex per rule in the grammar, and one right-vertex per nonterminal in the grammar.  Add an edge between nonterminal $A$ and each rule where $A$ appears on the right-hand side.  Now initialize a queue to be empty, repeat the following:

- For each rule $A \to \varepsilon$, mark $A$.  Whenever you mark a nonterminal that wasn't previously marked, add it to the queue.
- While the queue is non-empty:

  - Pop some nonterminal, call it $A$, from the queue.
  - For each edge from $A$ to some rule, delete that edge.  If the left-vertex for that rule now has no more edges out of it, mark the non-terminal on the left-hand side of that rule and add it to the queue if it wasn't already marked.

With an appropriate data structure for the graph, this runs in linear time.

Comment: thank you sir .